# Item section of an rss xml - any unique field

Tags: c#, php, jquery, xml, rss

I have a specification not to include the description element in a returned rss items to a mobile device. This is because the client claims the description text is too big for the mobile device to handle. The client is now asking there should be a unique field to identify each item that when sent to my application would retrieve the description for that item section.

My question is which of these elements value can be used to identify the item? I read that the `<guid>` element is not reliable and is an optional element.

```
  <item>
    <title>RSS Tutorial</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/rss</link>
    <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>
    <guid>http://www.w3schools.com/rss/item0768</guid>
    ...
    ...
  </item>
```

What I currently have in mind now is assume the items will always have a fixed position [1,2,3,4,5]. items[1] will always be items[1]. So I want to add another element `<index>i</index>`. Any suggestion? Thanks.

**update**

I think I need to focus on the implementation at hand. According to the rss specification, sub-elements in the item element are optional, and so is guid. Now it is present in the rss am working with, and I think I'll use that

Comment: Why don't you use `guid`? It should be unique for each `item` as per spec.

Comment: guid is an optional element, that's what got me worried. It's currently part of the rss am using, may be I should focus on that fact

Comment: From what you have said, i guess you control the rss structure. If that's right, `guid` is a good option to detect specific items.

Comment: @Pushpesh Thanks. I will stick with `guid`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953807/best-practice-to-keep-rss-feeds-unique-in-sql-database you need to read this one